# How to run Oracle scheduled job on Oracle Cloud autonomous DB?

Tags: oracle, job-scheduling, cron-task, oracle-cloud-infrastructure, oracle-autonomous-db

I am using always free autonomous DB on Oracle Cloud. I want to create the cron job which will be executed on every new row in the table eg. customers.

Can I run the script from a bucket or where do I need to upload the script which needs to be executed?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: If you have an Oracle database then why not use an Oracle scheduled job rather than a cron job? Or, if you want to to run on all new rows then create an insert trigger.

Comment: Can I run the scheduled job referencing script in the bucket or ?

Comment: Create a stored procedure and use the Scheduler to run that. Don't rely on external scripts; ADB doesn't have shell access to run OS-level scripts.

Comment: @pmdba I have a really large script like apex workspace export script, I should put it in the procedure?

Comment: A script like that is probably going to have to run from a remote client, using a tool like SQL Developer or SQL Plus. There's no real shell access in OCI with ADB unless you stand up a compute node just for that purpose; you can read a file in object storage like an external table, but there's no way to *execute* that file as a script, and you're right: it doesn't make sense to turn something like that into a stored procedure.

Comment: @pmdba Thanks, so for ADB it is not possible to run the script like that as scheduled job :(

Comment: There's no database server with an OS shell to run it from. You'd need to run it from some other network client with SQLPlus or SQLDeveloper.